# Export temp table data or stored procedure to excel using openrowset

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure within that I have created global temp table and normally 'select from temptable' giving output. When I use that in the openrowset command to export to excel getting error

```
    Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
    The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
    Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
    Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

First I tried with direct stored procedure only but same error
then with local temp table also same error 
then with global temp table its giving same error

When I use normal query I will get the excel file. My query is like bellow

```
    exec Proc_CardexSystem  @periodical_id=150,@periodicity='',@from_year=2014,@to_year=2018
    insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;Database="C:/Users/Mahantesh/Desktop/cardex.xlsx;',
    'select * from [CurrentCirculationList$]')select * from ##cte2_results
```

within procedure I have created temp table as bellow format and the procedure contains 'cte' also

```
    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##othertemp_table') is not null
    drop table ##othertemp_table
    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp_table ') is not null
    drop table ##temp_table 
    select columns into ##temp_table from ##othertemp_table
```

Comment: The error complains about the *ACE driver*, not the temp tables. Why don't you use SSIS? You can create an SSIS package quickly by using the Import/Export wizard in SSMS and save the package for editing and reuse

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I am using this with php codeigniter framework and not from management studio.

Comment: The *database* though is SQL Server. The ETL subsystem is SSIS. You don't need SSMS to execute an SSIS package. It's a *very* easy way to generate reusable import/export packages though. What you try to do though *requires* installing the ACE driver on the server. It also *requires* weakening security to allow writing/reading local folders. By default the databaase engine's account has no permissions to write to arbitrary folders

Comment: I have already installed the [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0] driver and given all permissions by reconfigure and getting the excel file when I pass normal table query. Getting error when I pass procedures or temptable query.\

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Hello sir, I am waiting for your reply.